# QGIS SVG with editable color and project var value

Tags: qgis

in QGIS we can make SVG colors editable by adding params:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
<rect fill="param(fill) #ff0000" stroke="param(outline) #00ff00" stroke-width="param(stroke-width) 10" width="100" height="100">
</rect>
</svg>
```

The optional parameter behind is the default.

Is it possible to have project vars as defaults? If so how is the correct syntax?

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
<rect fill="param(fill) @myfillcolor" stroke="param(outline) @myoutlinecolor" stroke-width="param(stroke-width) 10" width="100" height="100">
</rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - this is not possible. If you're using the SVGs as part of a symbol style you can achieve the same outcome by placing data defined overrides on the fill and outline colors and set them to the project variable.